# Python 3 - numerically labelling grid & adding borders?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to add numeric labelling, as well as a row and column to organize my game board for my program. I noticed it would work if I made emptyGrid = ["OOOO", "OOOO", "OOOO", "OOOO"], but sizeof_grid is supposed to represent any value that the user inputs, so I can't really make emptygrid equal to a set grid size. That being said, I can't get the program to display the grid labels when emptygrid = []. When I do that with my current program, it prints out nothing.

```
sizeof_grid = 4
emptyGrid = []

def initialize_board():
    start_board=[["O" for i in range(sizeof_grid)] for i in 
range(sizeof_grid)]
    return start_board

def players_board(grid): 
    for i in range(len(grid)): 
        print(str(i) + "|" + grid[i])
print(players_board(emptyGrid))
```

I would like the code to output something like:

### |01234

0|OOOOO

1|OOOOO

2|OOOOO

3|OOOOO

4|OOOOO

(without the spaces between each line)

Comment: You never call the `initialize_board` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code. You don't call the `initialize_board` function. Also, there are some bugs in the `players_board` function.

Modified code (lines with changes are commented with explaining the change):

```
sizeof_grid = 4
emptyGrid = []

def initialize_board():
    start_board = [["O" for i in range(sizeof_grid)] for i in 
range(sizeof_grid)]
    return start_board

def players_board(grid):
    print(" |" + "".join([str(x) for x in range(len(grid[0]))]))  # print the column numbers
    for i in range(len(grid)): 
        print(str(i) + "|" + "".join(grid[i]))  # convert the list to "" joined chars

emptyGrid = initialize_board()  # call this to initialize the board
players_board(emptyGrid)
```

HTH.